# Django 1.9.7 with bootstrap-admin doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I just knew bootstrap-admin today and I wanted to try it with my django project, but no matter how I changed my settings, the page doesn't show in a decent way, what have I done wrong?

(Django 1.9.7/Python 3.5.2/bootstrap-admin-0.3.6)

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'w!7!ah1(h_$e-s5=6=!53pti#z^drkwayc6k6e+-etfx&2lrje'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'bootstrap_admin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
]

from django.conf import global_settings


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_SIDEBAR_MENU = True

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':  'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Admin was completely restyled in Django 1.9. Last update of [`django-admin-boostrap`] was more than a year ago (which is prior to Django 1.9 release date).

And [an issue is opened](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrap/django-admin-bootstrap/issues/88) about this.

Anyway, the project looks dead. Pay much attention in the project state, history and updates frequency, when picking modules/apps. Especially if you are not experienced, its advisable to avoid using too much "unproved" modules. Otherwise, when bug occurs, it may be hard to find out if the problem comes from your code, from a third party module or from conflicting/incompatible third-party modules.

If you use only up-to-date and widely adopted modules, you can be pretty sure that if a bug occurs, you are to blame (which is a good thing).